# What is the final distribution of the path lengths when adding one node at a time

Tags: graph-theory

Imagine we build a directed graph as follows:
We start with one node, which we will call the root node.
Then, at each iteration, we add a new node and a directed edge from the new node to an existing node uniformly at random.
This process is repeated (if needed infinitely) many times.

If the path length is the number of edges to follow from a node to the root, the question is now what the distributions and expected values for the numbers of paths for all lengths are.

Comment: What's an "expected distribution"?

Comment: @joriki am likely using the wrong term here: what I would like to have is an expression telling how many paths of a given length there would be.

Comment: But it's a random process, so the number of paths of a given length is a random variable. Do you want the distributions for the numbers of paths for all lengths?

Comment: yes, I will update the question.

Comment: It's still not clear. You wrote "distribution" and "number" in the singular, but if you want it for all lengths, then there are plural numbers and distributions.

Comment: I see your point ... editing once more. I will add the expected value as well since that is what I am actually looking for.

Comment: Do you start off with a fixed set of nodes?  Or are you generating nodes according to some other process?

Comment: Numbering the nodes $1$, $2$, etc., and considering the length $L_n$ of the path from $n$ to $1$, one gets $L_1=0$ and $E(L_{n+1})=1+\frac1n(E(L_1)+\cdots+E(L_n))$ for every $n\geqslant1$. From which every $E(L_n)$ follows...